# How to get current rule name into outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Does anyone know how to parse the current rule name into outlook VBA

For example take the code below

The line(s) at the end could either use a number in the colrules.item statement, which will return the rule specified by the number, or you could be explicit if you knew the name of the rule so in the example if you knew the rule was called "My Rule" you could call that

However I don't want either of those, I want to return the name of the current rule that has called this piece of script when I don't know either the name of the rule or its index number

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim orule As Outlook.Rule 'this will be the specific rule
    Dim colrules As Outlook.Rules 'this will be the collection of rules, this is needed first to choose the specific rule from
      'Firstly we will get the current rule into our script so we can use the rule name to parse the vendor account into the filename
    Set colrules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules() ' get the collection of rules
    ' choose the specific rule that called this script
   Stop
    Set orule = colrules.Item(1)
Set orule = colrules.Item("My Rule")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to determine the current rule, or when certain rules have fired.